# LDAP simple bind to cross-forest Active Directory with 2-way trust

Tags: active-directory, trust-relationship

I have two forests (example.local and accounting.local) that have 2-way trust established. On accounting, I can bind using accounting\bind. However, it fails from example.local

ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C09042F, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v2580

I also have a child domain for example.local and I can bind using the credentials from the child on example.local. Tried various forms of naming, baseDN, global vs dc. Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

I tried it here and had the same result. According to [the Microsoft documentation for `ldap_simple_bind`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/winldap/nf-winldap-ldap_simple_bind):

> The **ldap_simple_bind** function is designed to bind to the local domain. The function cannot be used for cross forest authentication.

You will need to use a different (synchronous) bind method to cross forests. See the  [`ldap_bind_s` docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-ca/previous-versions/windows/desktop/api/winldap/nf-winldap-ldap_bind_s) for more details.

Comment: I am using UnboundId Java client from Linux which I believe is synchronous. I could not get this to work with adsi edit either.

Comment: It's not enough for the call to be synchronous. I just mean that all of the other bind methods (besides simple) must be called synchronously.

I tested this with `ldp.exe` and cross-domain logon works with other methods (eg _Bind with credentials_).

Comment: For this scenario with UnboundID LDAP, you should use SASL.